# int.times from Groovy in Java Streams

Tags: java, groovy, java-stream

I'm trying to create in Java 8 stream of ordered ints: `[1, 2, 3, 4, ...]`. In Groovy I would use i.e. `5.times { -lambda- }`. In Java I found only one way to do it and it is not very pretty:

```
    final IntStream.Builder builder = IntStream.builder();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        builder.add(i);
    }
    final IntStream stream = builder.build();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do

```
IntStream stream = IntStream.range(1, 5);
```